# Please add the ability to pause the real-time network questions

Tags: feature-request, realtime-questions

The real-time network questions page is cool, but could be better. I sometimes see a question I want to open - but it can be tricky because it is moving so fast (mostly Stack Overflow).

Please can there be a pause button somewhere?

Comment: But...then it's not real-time